# JQuery refresh a div on submit

Tags: jquery, html, web.py

I wanted to refresh a div when a user submits a simple form. However I can't seem to find out why it's not working. (It's my first time using JQuery and Ajax)

My Script:

```
 <script src="static/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script>
                $('#submit_div').click(function(){
                    var data: $("#name").val();
                    var datastr: 'name='+data;
                    $.ajax{
                        type: "POST",
                        url: $(this),
                        data: datastr,
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#content").replaceWith($('#content'),$(data));
                            }
                    }
                });

        </script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="content">
          <div id="form_div">
            <form method="POST">
                <div id="form"> 
                    <div id="name_div"> name <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/></div>
                    <div id="submit_div">  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">submit</button></div>
                </div>
            </form>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

Comment: I believe you are using '=' in place of ':', in your actual code. like var data = $('#name').val();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Errors**

```
var data: $("#name").val();
var datastr: 'name='+data;
$.ajax{...}
$("#content").replaceWith($('#content'),$(data));
```

**Fixed**

```
$('#submit_div').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                
    var data = $("#name").val();
    var datastr='name='+data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this),
        data: datastr,
        success: function(data){
            $("#content").replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an syntax error in your code. You should write:

```
var data = $("#name").val();
var datastr = 'name='+data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the jQuery Load method?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I don't really want to use another function, I want to know why this one is not working :). But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Oh ok. It looks like your using the replaceWith function wrong.

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

According to the jQuery site you only provide the replaceWith function with one argument, which is the new content.

Try removing the $('#content') from inside the replaceWith. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the returned value data is what u want to replacewith ( If i m right).. Then use like this..

```
$("#content").replaceWith(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form_div form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $("#name").val();
  $.post('/some/url/file.php',{name: data},function(data){
    $("#content").html(data);
  });
});
```

You should handle form submit event and prevent default action for it.